# Windows Builder Desiner display incorect with Eclipse(Neon.2) E4 RCP

Tags: windows, eclipse, builder, e4

I wanna use Windows Builder to design my Eclipse E4 RCP part，but the visual designer seems in trouble, please see my screen snapshot attached.

My system is:
OS: ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit

java:java version "1.8.0_92"

Eclipse: Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers
Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
Build id: 20161208-0600

WindowBuilder: WindowBuilder Pro for Eclipse [Integration Version 4.6 (Neon)](http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.6/)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It3EY.png)

Comment: Note: Do not use the default package for Eclipse RCP classes it won't work properly - always use a proper package.

Comment: oh? what do you mean? should I rename the part class package name?  or download windows builder for another version and where to get it?

Comment: i installed windows builder from here http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php  through Eclipse updater, with Eclipse Integration Version 4.6 (Neon) , as Neon release does not include WB. for Mars release it do contain WB, but the sample problem.